# RewriteURL not working in HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, url-rewriting

I have been searching other topics regarding this, but I seem to be at a lost at this one:

I have managed to create a modRewrite URL as the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/gui/?(.*)$ /webui/index.php?shell_file=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

This is working fine in HTTP, but when I go into HTTPS, it doesnt work. 
What do I need to change in order to make this work? I have followed many tutorials, but I just can't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: Is your Apache configured to handle HTTPS requests?

Comment: Yes, it is configured to handle HTTPS requests. Anything outside of the rewrite works fine. Its just anything within the rewrite that sais: Nope, i'm not doing this.